# How to map values to only empty rows in pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, mapping

I have a column where I want to map the data from a dictionary to only empty rows.And the rows that have some value or data already in it I dont want to map any data in it.

Expected Output:

```
|Column1 |Column2 |
|--------|--------|
|a       |        |
|        |Data    |
|c       |        |
```

My approach:
I tried to convert my column 1 into a list first:

```
for i in list:
    if i == '':
        df2['Column2'] = df2.x.map(er_dict)
    else:
        pass
```

Error I'm getting:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: so there missing `x` column and `er_dict` ?

Comment: X column and er_dict is something which I already have and the mapping works. But I only want to map it for empty rows in Column 1

Comment: I edited for loop code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
for c in cols:
    df2.loc[df2[c].eq(''), c] = df2.x.map(er_dict)
```